# How to use short division to represent the common divisor

Tags: xetex

I want to use short division to represent the common divisor.The following is my MWE：

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{2}{D{.}{}{2.0}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\doublerulesep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$}|>{$}r<{$}>{$}r<{$}}
2 & {84} & {96} \\\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{42} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$48$} \\\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{21} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$24$} \\\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$8$}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Looks a bit unsatisfactory,I want to achieve this effect:

[image]

Can someone achieve this more elegantly?

Comment: `@{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{0.5pt)(\normalbaselineskip}}` will add small gaps, and lose all the `\multicolumn`s.  Do you really want everything to drift to the right?

Comment: @John Kormylo As long as the output can be achieved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some trickery:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
\newcommand{\?}{\phantom{0}}
\begin{array}{rrrr@{\hspace{1em}}r}
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{2} &\?&\?& 84 & 96 \\
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{2}{r|}{2} &\?&    42 & 48 \\
\cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{3}{r|}{3} &       21 & 24 \\
\cline{4-5}
                       &&&      7 &  8 \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the definition of `\?` from `\phantom{0}` to `\mbox{}` you get

[image]

The intersection of the lines can be improved with `\hhline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,hhline}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
\newcommand{\?}{\mbox{}}
\begin{array}{rrrr@{\hspace{1em}}r}
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{2} &\?&\?& 84 & 96 \\
\hhline{~|----}
\multicolumn{2}{r|}{2} &\?&  42 & 48 \\
\hhline{~~|---}
\multicolumn{3}{r|}{3} &   21 & 24 \\
\hhline{~~~|--}
                       &&&  7 &  8 \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]